# Is it possible to write to a non 4-bytes aligned address with HLSL compute shader?

Tags: direct3d, hlsl, compute-shader, direct3d11, directcompute

I am trying to convert an existing OpenCL kernel to an HLSL compute shader.

The OpenCL kernel samples each pixel in an RGBA texture and writes each color channel to a tighly packed array.

So basically, I need to write to a tightly packed `uchar` array in a pattern that goes somewhat like this:

```
r r r ... r g g g ... g b b b ... b a a a ... a
```

where each letter stands for a single byte (red / green / blue / alpha) that originates from a pixel channel.

going through the documentation for `RWByteAddressBuffer` Store method, it clearly states:

```
void Store(
  in uint address,
  in uint value
);
```

> address [in]
>
> Type: uint
>
> The input address in bytes, **which must be a multiple of 4**.

In order to write the correct pattern to the buffer, I must be able to write a single byte to a non aligned address. In OpenCL / CUDA this is pretty trivial.

- Is it technically possible to achieve that with HLSL?
- Is this a known limitation? possible workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to write directly to a non aligned address in this scenario. You can, however, use a little trick to achieve what you want. Below you can see the code of the entire compute shader which does exactly what you want. The function `StoreValueAtByte` in particular is what you are looking for.

```
Texture2D<float4> Input;
RWByteAddressBuffer Output;

void StoreValueAtByte(in uint index_of_byte, in uint value) {

    // Calculate the address of the 4-byte-slot in which index_of_byte resides
    uint addr_align4 = floor(float(index_of_byte) / 4.0f) * 4;

    // Calculate which byte within the 4-byte-slot it is
    uint location = index_of_byte % 4;

    // Shift bits to their proper location within its 4-byte-slot
    value = value << ((3 - location) * 8);

    // Write value to buffer
    Output.InterlockedOr(addr_align4, value);
}

[numthreads(20, 20, 1)]
void CSMAIN(uint3 ID : SV_DispatchThreadID) {

    // Get width and height of texture
    uint tex_width, tex_height;
    Input.GetDimensions(tex_width, tex_height);

    // Make sure thread does not operate outside the texture
    if(tex_width > ID.x && tex_height > ID.y) {

        uint num_pixels = tex_width * tex_height;

        // Calculate address of where to write color channel data of pixel
        uint addr_red = 0 * num_pixels + ID.y * tex_width + ID.x;
        uint addr_green = 1 * num_pixels + ID.y * tex_width + ID.x;
        uint addr_blue = 2 * num_pixels + ID.y * tex_width + ID.x;
        uint addr_alpha = 3 * num_pixels + ID.y * tex_width + ID.x;

        // Get color of pixel and convert from [0,1] to [0,255]
        float4 color = Input[ID.xy];
        uint4 color_final = uint4(round(color.x * 255), round(color.y * 255), round(color.z * 255), round(color.w * 255));      

        // Store color channel values in output buffer
        StoreValueAtByte(addr_red, color_final.x);
        StoreValueAtByte(addr_green, color_final.y);
        StoreValueAtByte(addr_blue, color_final.z);
        StoreValueAtByte(addr_alpha, color_final.w);
    }
}
```

I hope the code is self explanatory since it is hard to explain, but I'll try anyway.
The fist thing the function `StoreValueAtByte` does is to calculate the address of the 4-byte-slot enclosing the byte you want to write to. After that the position of the byte inside the 4-byte-slot is calculated (is it the fist, second, third or the fourth byte in the slot). Since the byte you want to write is already inside an 4-byte variable (namely `value`) and occupies the rightmost byte, you then just have to shift the byte to its proper position inside the 4-byte variable. After that you just have to write the variable `value` to the buffer at the 4-byte-aligned address. This is done using `bitwise OR` because multiple threads write to the same address interfering each other leading to write-after-write-hazards. This of course only works if you initialize the entire output buffer with zeros before issuing the dispatch-call.

Comment: Thanks, I currently do it with OpenCL where I can also write the non aligned values to local memory (groupshared) and then have each thread write a single 4-byte value to the buffer. hlsl forces me to do 4 global atomic writes to whereas with OpenCL I can do single global write and 4 local non-atomic writes.